# How to sign in with apple in flutter the correct way?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I'm implementing the Apple login method in my **flutter** app. This is my code to sign in with Apple:

```dart
signInWithApple() async {
    var appleProvider = AppleAuthProvider();
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithProvider(appleProvider);
}
```

For some reason, the Apple sign in doesn't configure correctly in Firebase, mainly because when signing in with Apple, the user shows up in Firebase, but it [doesn't have an identifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6k3y.png)

I have done all the implementation correctly:

- I added Apple sign-in capabilities in Xcode and on apple developer
- I added the Apple sign-in method in firebase auth.
- I configured the info.plist files correctly
- The Apple sign in button redirects to the method above
- I've imported all the necessary packages correctly

I don't know how to fix this, I've tried using longer pieces of code, but these only seem to cause more trouble and errors.

It would be highly appreciated if anyone could provide an answer to my question.

---

Thank you in advance

Emiel

Comment: Hi have you found a fix for this? I experience the same thing. I don't even see the option to hide the email or not, it just shows the currently logged in apple id email and when I accept, appears to complete the call, but in Firebase Authentication, it shows the new UID but no email address in the identifier field. Completely stumped.

Answer (score 1):

when you sign in with apple in flutter you can provide or hide your email address to the auth provider, usually the hide email option is the default for privacy reasons, this doesnt means that there is an error, and even tho you dont see an identifier wich shoudl be the email, you should be able to see the userId in the last column of your users, so this is just and expected behavior

Comment: I also have to note that it once worked with my own email address, no idea why, but then it said this as identifier: 
ynftc...@privaterelay.appleid.com

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me by using AppleAuthProvider() like this:

```
AppleAuthProvider().addScope('email')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Complete Solution that i Implemented in my case

I had made a handler class in flutter to handle with [Sign in with Apple Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/sign_in_with_apple)

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple.dart';

class AppleSignInProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, dynamic>? userData;

  Future<void> login() async {
    final credential = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
      scopes: [
        AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
        AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
      ],
      webAuthenticationOptions: WebAuthenticationOptions(
        clientId: 'com.aboutyourapp.package',
        redirectUri:
            Uri.parse(
          'https://example.co/customer/auth/login/apple-mobile',
        ),
      ),
    );

    String base64EncodedString = credential.identityToken!.split('.')[1];

    // Calculate the number of padding characters needed
    int paddingNeeded = 4 - (base64EncodedString.length % 4);

    // Add padding characters to the Base64 string
    for (int i = 0; i < paddingNeeded; i++) {
      base64EncodedString += "=";
    }

    // Decode the Base64-encoded string
    List<int> decodedBytes = base64.decode(base64EncodedString);

    // Convert the decoded bytes to a string
    String decodedString = utf8.decode(decodedBytes);

    // Parse the JSON string into a Dart object
    Map<String, dynamic> decodedJson = json.decode(decodedString);

    userData = {
      'id': credential.authorizationCode,
      'token': credential.identityToken,
      'email': decodedJson["email"]
    };

    print(jsonEncode(userData));
  }

  logout() async {
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

keep in mind the redirect url must same as defined in apple store id section

and here is my backend (Laravel) code what i did with when Apple redirected me to my redirect url :

```
public function redirectToProvider(Request $request, $service)
    {
        if($service =="apple-mobile"){
            
            return redirect()->away('my_app_signinwithapple://? 
             code='.$request->code.'&id_token='.$request->id_token);
        }
        return Socialite::driver($service)->redirect();
    }
```

to listen **my_app_signinwithapple** in your app you also need to add it in AndroidManifest.xml inside the **application** tag

```
<activity
            android:name="com.aboutyou.dart_packages.sign_in_with_apple.SignInWithAppleCallback"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="my_app_signinwithapple" />
                <data android:path="callback" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

and for IOS you need to add in info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>my_app_signinwithapple</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```